# git pull --all does not work on worktrees

Tags: git

I use git 2.25.1 and the [worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) functionality. I have a main branch and a few orphan branches in other directories. If I execute `git pull --all` on the main directory, the pull happens as expected.

```
$ git pull --all
Fetching origin
Already up to date.
```

But if I want to push, it complains that one of the worktree directories is not up-to-date yet.

```
$ git push
Branch 'release-1.4' set up to track remote branch 'release-1.4' from 'origin'.'
stderr: 'To http://localhost:8080/foo.git
! [rejected]              bar -> bar (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://root@localhost:8080/foo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.'
```

Why does `git pull --all` not sync the worktree directories as well? Or does it do it, and I misinterpret the error message?

Comment: Not directly relevant, but note that the `--all` option is never useful with `git pull`.